# Is there any difference between WeakMap and private member of a class in JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out what is different between defining local/private properties and methods inside a class compared to WeakMap constructor?

is the purpose of hiding them from outside are the same or is there other thing to use them?

[image]

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: I just want to know what is the difference ?

Comment: there is no *private member* in es6 afaict. `x` is a local variable. like in any function.

Comment: @appleApple there is in ES8 :)

Comment: @JonasWilms isn't it still [stage-3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods#consensus-in-tc39)?

Comment: Again, PLEASE ADD THE CODE AS TEXT.

Comment: @appleApple yes, but I'm quite confident that it will be specified this year.

Comment: @JonasWilms I think it would be named ES10? I think ES8 is ES2017, or I got it wrong?

Comment: @appleApple oh right, yes ES10

Answer (score 1):

Given your current implementation:

- Your `let x` isn't very useful, because it can only be referenced in the constructor. It can't be used in any of the prototype methods. The WeakMap, on the other hand, can be referenced anywhere. That's a pretty big difference.
- Your WeakMap can be referenced anywhere. This means that it's not actually providing any privacy; anything with a reference to an instance and the WeakMap may access the `radius` value that you wanted to be private.

If you wanted the WeakMap to be *properly* private, via closures, you could use an IIFE to define the class, eg:

```
const myClass = (() => {
  const weakMap = new WeakMap();
  return class Circle {
    // etc
})();
```

That way, the top level only has a reference to the `myClass`, and not to the `weakMap`.

I would use your `let x` in the constructor whenever a variable is *only* needed in the constructor - not necessarily for the *sake* of hiding data, but just because it has no use outside of the constructor. See [Why is it good programming practice to limit scope?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307346/why-is-it-good-programming-practice-to-limit-scope)

Note that there is currently a proposal for [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) which will probably eventually be implemented, which includes syntax for private fields, eg:

```
class Circle {
  constructor(radius) {
    this.#x = radius;
    // ...
```

This will allow `#x` to be accessed from anywhere within `Circle`, but nowhere else. It's functionally equivalent to the `WeakMap` implementation.